# How To Update a UILabel as text is being typed in a UITextField

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield, uilabel, uitextfielddelegate

This is my first post to StackOverflow and I am also new to Xcode and Objective-C.
I have read about delegates and I have also experimented with other peoples code.  However, I wanted to see if I could create something myself that uses delegates without the aid of copying someone else's code.

What I am trying to do, to understand delegates, is to get a UITextField delegate to update a label every time a user types a key on the keyboard.

I created a xib file and connected a TextField to a UITextField *myTextField and a Label UILabel *myLabel in my .h file.

I also added  to the .h file of my ViewController Class.

However, I'm not sure what delegate method to use because the optional ones I can use as listed in the UITextFieldDelegate.h only seem to be able to update after Editing is finished.  Also I'm not sure if I should put the AppDelegate method in the .h file associated with my xib or the AppDelegate.h file.

I would appreciate any help with some direction on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you have a UITextField myTextField linked to your nib IB TextField object, and a UILabel myLabel linked to your nib IB Label object and you've made your Textfield point to your files owner then try this to see if it helps.

I just typed this up quickly, and I didn't test it, so check it for errors first.

```
// ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
    IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *myLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *myTextField;
@end


//  ViewController.m
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    myLabel.text = myTextField.text;
    return YES;   
}
```

Comment: This is a workaround, whereas you should use the `UITextInput` protocol

Comment: is there an applescript objc version for this? thank you

Answer (score 6):

You can add your UIViewController as a notification observer on the UITextField like so:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {
    // Create a label Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    // TextField Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
   // Select the textfield and in connection inspector drag a action from editing changed to the source code
    @IBAction func changed(_ sender: Any) {
       // Set text to label
        label.text = textField.text
        }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Delegate to self
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
    }
    // Implement the protocols
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
       textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }}
```

Comment: Basically you need an action and the protocol that correspond to it
if you wanna set the value to a instance variable you can do it in a action of didEndEditing but you must implement `code` textFieldDidEndEditing `